# Replace element in List with scala

Tags: scala, replace

How do you replace an element by index with an immutable List.

E.g.

```
val list = 1 :: 2 ::3 :: 4 :: List()

list.replace(2, 5)
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In addition to what has been said before, you can use `patch` function that replaces sub-sequences of a sequence:

```
scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> list.patch(2, Seq(5), 1) // replaces one element of the initial sequence
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 5, 4)

scala> list.patch(2, Seq(5), 2) // replaces two elements of the initial sequence
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 5)

scala> list.patch(2, Seq(5), 0) // adds a new element
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 5, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 108):

If you want to replace index 2, then

```
list.updated(2,5)    // Gives 1 :: 2 :: 5 :: 4 :: Nil
```

If you want to find every place where there's a 2 and put a 5 in instead,

```
list.map { case 2 => 5; case x => x }  // 1 :: 5 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil
```

In both cases, you're not really "replacing", you're returning a new list that has a different element(s) at that (those) position(s).

Answer (score 12):

You can use `list.updated(2,5)` (which is a method on `Seq`).

It's probably better to use a `scala.collection.immutable.Vector` for this purpose, becuase updates on `Vector` take (I think) constant time.

Comment: Not quite constant time, but logarithmic with a large base (which is close enough to "constant time with a pretty large constant" in practice).

Comment: @Alexey An `updated` on `Vector` does not depend on the index, as opposed to an `updated` on `List`, which is `O(index)`. That makes it really constant time for fixed-size collections, which might well apply. I'm not denying what you said, but I think this is an interesting point.

Comment: @Daniel: so is it correct to say that `updated` on `List` is `O(index)` and `updated` on `Vector` is `O(lg size)`, which may make `List` advantageous when `size` is huge but `index` is small? (I'd love to know where to find more information about the time guarantees of Scala's immutable structures.)

Comment: Vector is `O((log size)/32)`. In fact, the maximum number of nesting levels it accepts is 6, each of which has 32 elements. So, for the biggest collection possible, you'd have to copy 6 * 32 elements. Updating a `List` might well win if you know for sure only the first few elements will be updated, but it soon starts losing any advantage. As for looking it up, there's http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html, but you may also check the implementation itself through a link on Scaladoc.

Comment: Another point is that `Vector` has good spatial locality of reference, so it is cache-friendly. `List`, on the other hand, has very bad locality of reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a lot of such replacements, it is better to use a muttable class or Array.

Comment: There are a lot of other... *issues* ...that come with using mutable data structures, so be sure you are cognizant of that before deciding to use them.

Comment: I agree there are issues. But there are also issues with using non-mutable data structures for mutable data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use map to generate a new list , like this :

```
@ list
res20: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4)
@ list.map(e => if(e==4) 0 else e)
res21: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 5, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

It can also be achieved using patch function as

```
scala> var l = List(11,20,24,31,35)

l: List[Int] = List(11, 20, 24, 31, 35)

scala> l.patch(2,List(27),1)

res35: List[Int] = List(11, 20, 27, 31, 35)
```

where 2 is the position where we are looking to add the value, `List(27)` is the value we are adding to the list and 1 is the number of elements to be replaced from the original list.

Answer (score 0):

following is a simple example of String replacement in scala List, you can do similar for other types of data

```
    scala> val original: List[String] = List("a","b")

    original: List[String] = List(a, b)

    scala> val replace = original.map(x => if(x.equals("a")) "c" else x)

    replace: List[String] = List(c, b)
```

Comment: Where does `cols` come from? How is this answer different than the 2-year old answer from damon-lin?