# count char frequency in string with scala

Tags: scala

I search a way to count the different chars from a string.
The problem is that's *not allowed to use any functions from the scala-api or to use vars* (only val).

I want same result like that

```
val fruit: String = "dasisteintest"
println(fruit.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size))
Map(e -> 2, s -> 3, n -> 1, t -> 3, a -> 1, i -> 2, d -> 1)
```

In every try I made, I have at the end a `list[(Char,Int)]` where I have to change the Int. But because it's an immutable list I can't change it.
How can I implement that counting char algorithm?

Comment: Not clear what your actual question is. Assuming you're not just after someone answering your assignment for you, where are you stuck? What is the output supposed to look like? `Map` (and `groupBy`) are part of the scala-api so it's not clear what you want here. What can you use?

Comment: As I write above I need the **same result** like `fruit.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)` but **without functions from the scala-api**. All of my tries are failing because every time I need to change one element of a List. I know that I "only" have to make e new List with the changed element. But I dont know how I can realize it to make a new List with the changed element. So I hoped that someone can help me to change an element of a List (without functions from the api) or someone has an other way to count the different chars from a string... hope now every thing is clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the expected code.
First the function which returns the char from the list

```
    def removeFromList(l: List[Char], l2: List[Char], toDelete: Char): List[Char] = {
       if (l.isEmpty) l2
       else {
           if (l.head == toDelete)
              removeFromList(l.tail, l2, toDelete)
           else 
              removeFromList(l.tail, l2 :+ l.head, toDelete)
       }
    }
```

and then the function which counts the chars and calls `removeFromList()`

```
def zaehlZeichen(s: String): List[(Char, Int)] = {
    val sl: List[Char] = s.toUpperCase().toList
    if (sl.isEmpty) Nil
    else {
      val l: List[Char] = List()
      val tupleList: List[(Char, Int)] = List();
      val in: Int = countChar(sl, 0, sl.head)
      val t: List[(Char, Int)] = tupleList :+ (sl.head, in)
      val cutL: List[Char] = removeFromList(sl, l, sl.head)
      t ::: zaehlZeichen(cutL.mkString);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet:

```
val fruit: String = "dasisteintest"
val map = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[Char, Int]
for (symbol <- fruit) {
  if (map.contains(symbol))
    map(symbol) = map(symbol) + 1
  else
    map.+=((symbol, 1))
}
println(map)
```

Comment: uhh yes cool, thank you! To write the contains method on my own is not so difficult, I think. I will try it right now.

Comment: My guess is the answer isn't supposed to use mutable collections, but only the OP knows for sure.

Comment: @The-archetypal-paul from the question's penultimate sentence one could infer that the collection supposed to be changed.

Comment: @theoretisch You could use Java's `HashMap` (which is definitely not scala api) in order to not implement `contains` and `+=` methods.

Comment: @Aliaxander, one could. I would infer that the OP hasn't yet understood how to do this with immutable collections, though, and just doesn't see how to do without modifying the list. I'm guessing this is the point of the assignment. Since vars are not permitted, my guess is mutable collections aren't either.

Comment: @the-archetypal-paul Now I see, your OP question interpretation seems closer than mine.

Comment: yes, I have to do it without mutable collections... sorry I am new is scala.
the hashmap from java is an mutable collection too, isnt it ?

Comment: @theoretisch Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "no functions from Scala API"? Does that include no functions from the collections api? If so, then ignore my answer. However if we can't even use reduce  methods, I don't see the point of this exercise.

Here's what I came up with:

```
val fruit: String = "dasisteintest"
fruit.foldLeft[Map[Char,Int]](Map.empty)((map, c) => map + (c -> (map.getOrElse(c, 0) + 1)))
```

Although can you expand what you mean by ""you have to change the Int"?

Comment: thank you, but .foldLeft and .getOrElse are functions from the scala api, isnt it ? If I want to realize it like you I have to write these functions on my own....

Comment: What is your assignments definition of Scala API

Comment: The definition is only "dont use functions from the scala-api"..
Do you think there are any differences between functions?

Answer (score 1):

```
def countChars(str: String) = {
  def loop(chars: List[Char], acc: Map[Char, Int]): Map[Char, Int] = {
    chars match {
      case Nil => acc
      case char :: rest =>
        loop(rest, acc + (char -> (acc(char) + 1)))
    }
  }

  loop(str.toList, Map.empty[Char, Int] withDefaultValue 0)
}
```

Test:

```
@ val fruit: String = "dasisteintest" 
fruit: String = "dasisteintest"
@ countChars(fruit) 
res4: Map[Char, Int] = Map('e' -> 2, 's' -> 3, 'n' -> 1, 't' -> 3, 'a' -> 1, 'i' -> 2, 'd' -> 1)
```

Whatever you use here is from scala api, a `Map.apply`, or `Map.empty` or `List.::`. It would be difficult not to use *any* functions from scala api. My guess is that you aren't supposed to be using things like `groupBy` and you are supposed to do something a bit more low level. Folding is natural solution here, like `foldLeft`, but if that is considered "using a function from scala api", you can just implement `foldLeft` yourself, just like I did in my solution.

As for `withDefaultValue` you can replace it with explicit check if value is present and put a 1 there in that case.

You don't know how to change an in a list or map that is immutable? You just make a new list with that value changed.

For a map, given

```
val map = Map('a' -> 3)
```

you can update it doing

```
@ map.updated('a', 4) 
res6: Map[Char, Int] = Map('a' -> 4)
```

or

```
@ map + ('a' -> 4) 
res7: Map[Char, Int] = Map('a' -> 4)
```

Both do exact the same thing - insert or update - and return new map.

Here you can find how to update elements in a list

[Replace element in List with scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062435/replace-element-in-list-with-scala)

although you rarely want to access list by index, you rather just build a new list from old one while iterating over it somehow, e.g. with fold.

Comment: thank you, the solution with the match is cool. That solves the problem with my List perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
object CountEachCharInString 
{
  //Counts the number of a specific character in the Input String
  def characterCount(inputChar: Char, str: String): Unit = 
  {
    var num: Int = 0
    num = str.count(_ == inputChar);
    
/*
    //Implementation of count method
    for(i <- 0 to str.length - 1)
    {
      if(str(i) == inputChar) 
      {
        num += 1
      }
    }
*/
    println(s"$inputChar appears $num times")
  }
  
  
  def countAllChars(inputStr: String): Unit = 
  {
    
    //To eliminate duplicates, need one loop inside the other. str(i) == str(j)
    for(i <- 0 to inputStr.length - 1)
    {
      var occurence: Int = 0
      
      for(j <- 0 to i-1)
      {
        if(inputStr(j) == inputStr(i))
            occurence = occurence + 1
      }
      
      if(occurence == 0)
      {
        characterCount(inputStr(i), inputStr)
        //var num = inputStr.count(_ == inputStr(i))
        //println( inputStr(i) + s" appears $num times")
      }        
    }
  }
  
  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
    countAllChars("HelloforHello...^^&&&&")
  }
}
```

Comment: The question clearly states, _"not allowed to ... use vars (only `val`)"_.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.